# How to make a JavaScript function that will delete table rows from a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

As the title says, I was wondering if there is any way to create a function in JavaScript that will delete a row from a table? Maybe by calling some PHP to delete a row in the table?

Comment: Start with reading a book about it. Cures the wondering disease. ;)

Comment: I find solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: A little hint: You'll find both parts answered on this site. So if you split the question and search for each part you'll find useful stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example if you have a table with a few columns, add a new column with some `delete me` button:

```
<tr rel="34">
  <td>34</td>
  <td>Joe</td>
  <td><a class="deleteRow" href="#">delete me</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then in `jQuery` for example add a click event to `.deleteRow` class:

```
$('.deleteRow').click(function(){
  var parent = $(this).parent('tr');
  var rowId  = parent.attr('rel');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "delete.php",
    data: {id:rowId},
    success: function(){
      parent.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

And in `delete.php` script:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
  $id = (int) $_POST['id'];
  // make sql query to remove element with given id
}
```

Comment: And if jQuery is an option :)

Comment: If so - it was the quickest way to explain it for me. If it is not available, then OP should implement it by his own. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to call a php function from javascript is by making an ajax call. Since javascript is client side and php is server side so there is no other way to do so.